# Unable to use TailWindcss with React-native

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

For the past several hours I have been trying to make tailwindcss work with react-native expo application. But it is not working as I have expected it to work. I have tried every possible fix I can think of including the fixes suggested in stackoverflow or google. So is there a way to incorporate tailwindcss with react-native. I know there are other packages like 'twrc' which is excellent, but not the way I want it. So can anyone help

```
    //tailwind.config.js
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: [
        "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./navigation/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
    
    //babel config file
    module.exports = function (api) {
      api.cache(true);
      return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: ["nativewind/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
      };
    };
    
    //Package.json file
    {
      "name": "coin-pay-mob",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
        "axios": "^1.6.2",
        "expo": "~49.0.15",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
        "lottie-ios": "^4.3.3",
        "lottie-react-native": "^6.4.1",
        "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.6",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.4",
        "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
        "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
        "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1",
        "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0",
        "tailwindcss-react-native": "^1.7.10",
        "twrnc": "^3.6.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.31",
        "tailwindcss": "3.2.2"
      },
      "private": true
    }

//Homepage.jsx
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const StudentLogin = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-neutral-600">
      <Text className="font-bold">StudentLogin</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default StudentLogin;
```